# PHP Date conversion to unix-timestamp

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp, type-conversion

How do yo convert this 2014-11-03 17:01:37 into Unix Timestamp?
Is there a method that I can use.

Comment: [`strptime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `DateTime` object:

```
$time = new DateTime("2014-11-03 17:01:37");
$time->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

use - `strtotime()`

```
$date = "2014-11-03 17:01:37";
echo strtotime($date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strtotime('2014-11-03 17:01:37')
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a [function `strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for that purpose.

```
echo strtotime("2014-11-03 17:01:37");
```